# Add class with delay JQuery then remove and loop this function

Tags: javascript, jquery

got this problem were i need this function to work as a loop (or atleast i think thats what I want).

It works the first time I enter #nav and leave but the second time I want to enter the navigation the addClass function is not working.

```
$("#nav").mouseenter(function() {
    $(".desktop a").delay(300).queue(function(){$(this).addClass('showhidden')});
});
$("#nav").mouseleave(function() {
    $(".desktop a").removeClass("showhidden");
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to dequeue it:

```
$(".desktop a").dequeue().delay(300).queue(function(){$(this).addClass('showhidden')});
```

And:

```
$(".desktop a").dequeue().removeClass("showhidden");
```

Or just use:

```
 $(".desktop a").clearQueue().removeClass("showhidden");
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove Class

```
         setTimeout(function() {
            elements.removeClass(className);
        }, 4000);
```

Add Class

```
       setTimeout(function() {
            elements.attr('class','classname');
        }, 4000);
```